# What does it mean when we say "A is B's lover"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence

For example, suppose we have the sentence:

**Bianca is Ed's lover.**

What does this mean?

**Bianca loves Ed? Ed loves Bianca? It is mutual?**

I don't really understand the word 'lover' in this context.

Comment: What did you find in the dictionary definition of "lover"?

Comment: What´s _love_ got to do with it?

Comment: To be lovers means they have an ongoing intimate relationship. Ongoing means, by definition, mutual. Intimate means they treat private times together like they are practicing for the wedding night. Socially, it means they are treated like a couple.

Comment: @Yosef Maybe, maybe not.   This, from OED and similarly, many on-line dictionaries: _3b. A person who engages in a romantic or sexual relationship outside marriage, esp. one which is clandestine or illicit._

Answer (score 2):

Nearly always means the two of them are sexually and/or romantically involved, and could just as accurately be stated the other way around: "Ed is Bianca's lover." "Lover" COULD mean "one who is pining for the other," but most people are going to take it in the "they're sleeping together" sense rather than the unrequited-love sense.